# Web API Dependency Resolver in Windows Azure Web Sites

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api

After publishing a project with WebAPI to Windows Azure Web Sites, I started getting exceptions tossed complaining that my API controllers didn't implement a default constructor.

I'm using Ninject in my project, and when I explicitly register the NinjectDependencyResolver in my GlobalConfiguration, the issue in Azure is resolved.

What I'm puzzled by is why I don't encounter this issue on my local development machine. Can anyone explain the configuration different in MAWS that causes this extra step to be necessary?

Comment: Are you sure you did not get this issue locally? Registering `DependencyResolver` in `GlobalConfiguration` is a critical step in DI configuration for WebApi. And MAWS is almost no different from a local IIS

Comment: Quite positive, why I was so puzzled by the behavior!